# My HDD is unallocated how to restore

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, backup

I accidentally removed all partitions on my external USB HDD.
All my pictures were on it, as this device was my Photo backup.

Steps I took:

1. I started with my WD Harddisk 1TB with 2 partitions, one with my photo's (500GB) and 380GB for **Misc**.
2. Add new partition for Linux (10GB), it was called **J:** I took space from **Misc**, as there was nothing valuable on it.
3. Install Linux Kali (via Win32Disk Imager) to partition **J:** - this gave an error, and I'm now stuck with: 3GB partition and 980 unallocated space
4. My disk has now a 3GB partition and 980 unallocated space.

Is there anything I can try to restore my partitions or at least get the most of it back?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use file recovery software if you have written nothing since you performed the format.  Of course there is no guarantee which is the reason multiple backups are important to have.

Answer (score 0):

Before doing anything, I would run [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) on the whole disk to try to rescue all the recovereable images.

Then you can try to recover the original partition using [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk). However, if the partition table was corrupted, the file system may also have been damaged (some photos may have been overwritten). That's why I think you should get the photos out as soon as possible, before attempting to repair the mess.